# How to remove tii.la cookie in Linux?

Tags: linux, browser, utilities, cookie

I'm using Brave browser ver 1.56.20 in MX Linux 21.3 (Debian 11 based), how can I remove cookies in Brave? Tried to use remove icon, it does not work, seems it's a known bug in Brave (over a year old and not solved yet), installed BleachBit, did not work either (BleachBit forum is closed for new users), is there any other way to remove cookies installed by third party without your permission? Any other tools?

Answer (score 1):

I don't personally use Brave, but by googling a bit and putting together the bits of information available in answers regarding different OSs, in Linux the cookies would seem to be stored in a file named `Cookies`, located in directory `~/.config/BraveSoftware/Brave-Browser/Default/`.

Apparently you can remove the entire file while Brave is stopped, and then Brave will just create a new empty cookie file when you start it again.

Sources:
https://community.brave.com/t/where-does-brave-store-its-data-files/53830
https://community.brave.com/t/restoring-deleted-cookies/260172

Comment: Thanks so much for this tip, will give a try, found another possibility by this https://community.brave.com/t/cookies-issue-some-cookies-can-not-be-deleted/429066/2, it seems somehow the site in question "disabled" Brave shield on such site, the solution is go to the site in question (in my case tii.la and enable Brave shield again, and voila, the cookie is deleted).